# Flash CS3 static text fields do not show intended font

Tags: flash, flash-cs3

In flash I have static text fields using a non standard font. In the IDE it looks fine, however in exported swf's they default to a default font. When I change the font to dynamic and embed the font it works fine. However using a static field doesn't show the font at all.

Anyone have any ideas as to why this is? Is this a bug or glitch?

Is it because it is static font within a movieclip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this problem.  Check the name of your embedded font, and make sure it's not the same name as the font you're using for the static text.  Rename it to something like "[font name] embedded".

I think the Flash IDE gets confused when you try to use static text with a font that's embeded.  Weird bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Are you using some special character ? I had to display Greek text and it wouldn't display in static fields with Arial. I had to find an Arial that had Greek Characters ( Helios or something ).